# How to hide / remove / rename "Name" propertie from folders

Tags: content-type, folder, display-name, rename

I have a content Type that inheritate from Folder (named F_CT) to content my other type elements (I_CT)... When I Click to create a new F_CT Sharepoint asks me how all the F_CT fields and "Name" as it inheritate from Folder..

How could I "Remove" that field from the view? Is there any way to hide it? If I hide it I could associate the value I want with an Event Handler or something like that...

Is possible to rename if? Or assign it another display name?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done.

If you remove the name from the content type folder, the folder will become unusable. Changing the display name is also not an option because it will affect the files that should be stored in the library to.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that, while you can't delete the Name field, you could hide it in the edit form using jquery.  There are a lot of articles on how to do this. Then you are right, you would need a way to populate it anyway, and I'm not sure an event receiver would work.  Perhaps if it was on the "ItemAdding" event.